# Eclipse PHP - cannot find validation section to exclude .xml files from validation

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Using Eclipse for PHP Developers Version: 3.0.2 ([latest Zend download](http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt/downloads))

What I want to do, is to exclude some **single** `.xml` / `.html` files from validation. Seemed to be straight forward.

1. SO " https://stackoverflow.com/a/5288496/356726 " says to use `Project / Properties / Validation`,  but I do  not have this menu item.
2. SO " [How to exclude specific folders or files from validation in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272237/how-to-exclude-specific-folders-or-files-from-validation-in-eclipse) " refers to `Window / Preferences`. I checked through the sections  in order to find the exclude sections,  but I was unable  to locate it. I can set project specific settings, but where do I exclude single files?

What do I miss? I am sure it is pretty simple.

Project Properties:

[image: Project Properties]

Window / Preferences:

[image: Preferences]

Comment: Try updating your IDE.

Comment: When I say "Check updates", none are found. However PDT seems to be 3.2, maybe  will try reinstall of  3.2.

Comment: OK  3.0.2 is the latest Zend version for an all-in-once installation as of today. So I am on the newest version. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The latest PDT version is 3.1.2 today. Your 3.0.2(Zend distribution) is too much old. BTW, you need PDT and 'Eclipse Web Developer Tools' features.

Comment: So you recommend to uninstall the Zend version an reinstall the Eclipse version?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (Eclipse Indigo, Java project):

1. project -> right click -> Properties -> Validation
2. check Enable project specific settings
3. XmlValidator: check Manual, check Build, click "..." for Settings
4. Add Exclude Group, select it
5. Add Rule -> Folder or file name -> select file you want to ignore
6. refresh project (or close and open)

This instruction assumes the button Add Exclude Group in step 4 is enabled. However, in my case the button was disabled. I don't know the reason but I discovered following workaround:

4a. Add (empty) Include Group
 4b. Open file PROJECT_HOME.settings\org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs 
 4c. Edit key vals/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xml/groups - change 07include00 to 07exclude00 near the end of string
 4d. Refresh project, open project properties again