# .gitignore won't let me upload files

Tags: git, github

I'm learning to use github and here's my problem.

I uploaded my program to github as always (git add, commit, push).
Then I noticed that the files in one of the folders are missing, replaced by .gitignore

The contents of the "src" folder should be as follows:

```
src -> model, controller
    model -> x.java, y.java z.java
    controller -> w.java
```

Instead of the above, there is only a single .gitignore file in src. The contents of the file are something like:

```
/model/
/controller/
```

Why did this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: `.gitignore` files usually do not appear magically all around. Are you sure it's a project of yours? Did you copy something from somewhere else? Anyway, simply drop the file from the `src`.

Answer (score 1):

That can happen for instance with EGit: the  preference settings under `Team > Ignored Resources` can define "derived" flag, which will generate a .gitignore.

If model and controller folder were considered as "derived" (ie "generated"), EGit might have generated that .gitignore.

To fix it, [check your preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589400/6309),

[image: derived]

Also `git add --force` those folders, delete that .gitignore, commit and push.