# Can Eclipse be configured to disable warnings for derived source files?

Tags: java, eclipse, derived

I am using ANTLR to generate Java source files. I can make Eclipse understand the generated files are derived, but it still gives me warnings about harmless things (e.g. unnecessary imports and so on). I would like to configure Eclipse to ignore derived files when showing warnings. Is this possible?

Comment: See Knubo's answer to [How to suppress Java warnings for specific directories or files such as generated code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127920/how-to-suppress-java-warnings-for-specific-directories-or-files-such-as-generated/3749955#3749955) for a way to use maven to automatically add the @SuppressWarnings annotations.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127920/how-to-suppress-java-warnings-for-specific-directories-or-files-such-as-generate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid that what you see (in the Preferences) is what you get.

However, if you're going to have ANTLR producing code for you anyway, why not go one step further and have your build script (ant, Maven, ...) wrap that code into a Jar for you? Set up that Jar file as your dependency in Eclipse and Eclipse won't have to look at the ugly auto-generated code and throw a fit about it.

Comment: OK, that is what I ended up doing. Not overly elegant, but it works. And my OCD tendency to keep a warning-free workspace can continue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could put the derived or autogenerated files into a separate eclipse project and apply special project properties to that 'derived files' project, like to not show Warnings for unused imports.

Different settings in the same project for different packages or source folders are not possible, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835628/932359). Since Eclipse 3.8 we can ignore warnings on specific source folders.