# How to get rid of generics warnings in code generated from xmlbeans-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, generics, maven-2, xmlbeans

I have some code generated from xsd files by xmlbeans-maven-plugin. Unfortunately generated code uses raw collection types, like:

```
java.util.List targetList = new java.util.ArrayList();
get_store().find_all_element_users(CURRENCY$0, targetList);
Currency[] result = new Currency[targetList.size()];
targetList.toArray(result);
```

which causes lots of warnings.
Is there a way to force the plugin to generate generic types or generate `@SupressWarnings` annotations?
I use maven v 2.0.9, xmlbeans-maven-plugin v 2.3.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127920/how-to-suppress-java-warnings-for-specific-directories-or-files-such-as-generated

Comment: @johnbk - this may be an option, but I hoped the plugin could handle this, not Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just generate generified code using a [javaSource parameter](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xmlbeans-maven-plugin/xmlbeans-mojo.html) of 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the source and target jdk versions to pre-1.5 to get rid of those warnings. 
[Setting source version](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Compile+and+Test+with+Different+JDK+Versions)

e.g.

```
          <configuration>
               <source>1.4</source>
               <target>1.4</target>
           </configuration>
```