# What Maven XMLBeans configuration must be set to use generics?

Tags: java, generics, configuration, maven, xmlbeans

There are a few XMLBeans sites that make reference to generated code taking advantage of generics (and enums) however, I can't seem to find the configuration option to set.

Sites mentioning generics in XML Beans:
http://xmlbeans.apache.org/news.html
http://wiki.apache.org/xmlbeans/V2Features

I have set the `javaSource` configuration to 1.5 but that still isn't causing the generated source to use generics.
(see http://mojo.codehaus.org/xmlbeans-maven-plugin/xmlbeans-mojo.html#javaSource)

Some related Stack Overflow questions:

- [How to get rid of generics warnings in code generated from xmlbeans-maven-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803346/how-to-get-rid-of-generics-warnings-in-code-generated-from-xmlbeans-maven-plugin)
- [How to suppress Java warnings for specific directories or files such as generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127920/how-to-suppress-java-warnings-for-specific-directories-or-files-such-as-generated)

Comment: *(I am unfortunately limited to 2 hyperlinks, so you'll have to cut'n'paste)* that sucks. edited for you.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your POM? I use <javaSource>1.5</javaSource> and it works fine

Comment: @artbristol , here it is and sorry about the formatting (I should note that the rest of the project is java 1.6 however changing it to 1.5 had no effect):
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.3</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>xmlbeans</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<inherited>true</inherited>
<configuration>
<schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
<sourceGenerationDirectory>src/main/java</sourceGenerationDirectory>
<javaSource>1.5</javaSource>
</configuration>
</plugin>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@artbristol was correct, simply use the 'javaSource' tag.

Looks like we were using 'javasource' (notice case) and that was the problem. When the case issue was resolved, the target directory wasn't being cleaned properly, leaving some legacy Java 1.4 files which was the cause of the compiler warnings.

Thanks!