# Is it possible to suppress warnings in a specific directory?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

In my project I had to copy a library into my source to make some minor adjustments.
This library throws a couple of warnings when compiling. I don't like that ;-)

Since I don't want to change the library code any more than absolutely necessary, I do not want to put `@Suppress` lines into the library code.

Is there a possability to advise the compiler "Please ignore warnings, but only in `src/foo/bar`"? Maybe a compiler flag?
I am using a Gradle build, if that opens additional options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo.bar` is a package and packages [can not be suppressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910759/why-cant-i-suppresswarnings-on-a-package).

Your options are:

1. [Remove compiler warnings entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572602/gradle-compilejava-remove-compile-warnings)
2. Create separate [source set](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) and [compile task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html) for the problematic code.
3. Fix the warnings.