# How to ignore compiler warnings in Eclipse for generated code when using Gradle's Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a Java library that includes a large amount of generated code in the `src/gen/java` directory.  The code generator isn't very mature, so the generated code triggers tons of Eclipse warnings.  While it's relatively easy to [suppress these warnings manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835628/1475872), they come back the moment I regenerate the project.  I also want to avoid any manual steps when cloning the repository and setting up the project for the first time.  How can I instruct Gradle to automatically ignore the compiler warnings in a generated Eclipse project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have something like this in your `build.gradle` already:

```
apply plugin: "eclipse"

sourceSets {
    main {
        srcDirs += ["src/gen/java"]
    }
}
```

Add the `eclipse` block below:

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged {
                entries.each { entry ->
                    if (entry.kind == "src" && entry.path.endsWith("src/gen/java")) {
                        entry.entryAttributes["ignore_optional_problems"] = "true"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle will generate a `.classpath` file with a classpath entry that results in Eclipse ignoring compiler warnings for source in the `src/gen/java` directory:

```
<classpathentry output="bin/main" kind="src" path="src/gen/java">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
        <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value"main,test"/>
        <attribute name="ignore_optional_problems" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```