# Is there a way to tell eclipse to ignore warnings from specific code folders?

Tags: eclipse, warnings, javadoc

This is a longshot question, so bear with me. :)

I like to have my code warning free so that I can quickly determine if I have a warning that truly needs to be dealt with.  I have it set that if certain javadoc items are not correct, it will display a warning.  In the team I work with, they are not concerned with javadoc warnings in the unit tests.  These tests are always at src/test/java.  Unfortunately if there is a warning in the test, it not only shows the warning icon on the code folder src/test/java, but also on the project itself.  I'm tempted just to javadoc all of their unit tests, but it's not a good use of my time.  Is there a way to tell eclipse to ignore warnings from src/test/java or trigger different warnings for my tests than for my implementation?

Comment: The only options like that that I've seen are project wide and can't be scoped to a folder

Answer (score 1):

You can use a working set to filter out the test code.  Take a look at this answer: [Filtering warnings in eclipse by filename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232473/274350)

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding something, this suggests that I put my tests in a separate assembly than my implementation.  Is that correct?  If so, it's a no-go.

Comment: You should be able to define a working set that includes some files and folders of a project but not all.  When defining the working set, expand the project and add only the parts that you want.  This might be a pain to do if the tests are intermingled with code, but should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try it out.  The tests are not intermingled with the code, but are in the same maven project.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one good answer in [How to suppress Java warnings for specific directories or files such as generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127920/how-to-suppress-java-warnings-for-specific-directories-or-files-such-as-generate)
(using Project properties > Java Build Path > Compiler > Source)